# How to use a basic Google Sheets javascript script in GitHub Pages?

Tags: javascript, github-pages, google-sheets-api, sheetrock

Trying to implement a piece of code to display data from a Google Spreadsheet in my GitHub Pages page. I found [Sheetrock.js](http://chriszarate.github.io/sheetrock/) and the JS Fiddle worked, but I'm missing how to setup a basic javascript file structure. I know I can name files ___.js and call them from the html file, but the Sheetrock.js info doesn't use this format. I remember trying this a while ago and after hitting the same roadblocks gave up, so I'm posting to hopefully save others, coming from a similar search for using GSheets in a static site through javascript, hours of searching on such a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for hours (through Jekyll tutorials and other JS package installations). I know this seems simple now, but there was only one basic [javascript setup](https://dev.to/programliftoff/create-a-basic-webpage-with-css-and-javascript--104i) I finally found that answered it after searching on 'javascript', 'github pages', and even [jquery with GH](https://code-maven.com/javascript-on-github-pages).

So the basic answer seems to be to simply create an index.js file next to index.html, and this is of course where all the generic javascript goes. The  tags and external http CDN js file imports go in the HTML file.

You can use other javascript means such as [JSON based access](https://nobleintentstudio.com/blog/google-docs-as-a-backend/) to connect to GSheet data, but Sheetrock.js seems to be doing okay.

There are also ways to adjust the iframe to select columns and use the SQL language base using the [Google Google Visualization API Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) described in [this page](https://acrl.ala.org/techconnect/post/query-a-google-spreadsheet-like-a-database-with-google-visualization-api-query-language/). The SQL type commands carry over to the Sheetrock.js usage.